# Launching MySQL without a password

Tags: mysql

I have installed MySQL. During the process of installation I was asked whether I want to determine a password for root user. Well, I entered a password.

Now I can access it through
mysql -u root -p

Well, it works.

The question is what will happen if I use just mysql command?
Well. This is what appears:

```
mysql>
```

I'm a bit confused. If I organize a password, how can I get access without entering it.
What privileges do I have in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you can "enter" MySQL doesn't mean that you have the ability to do anything. Try and create a database without supplying a password. Try and access a database without the password... I'm fairly sure that you won't be able to do either.

Comment: Well, why should I need such entrance?

Comment: You can see that the service is running, I suppose. Other than that, it is fairly useless, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

You are connected as ROOT (you can create,detele, alter,procedures,triggers,tables,configurations, users, Dbs, etc) , so you can do whatever you want. It's the same if you do:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

or

```
mysql -u root -p "my_root_pass"
```

(of course if you have one)

the `mysql>` just mean that you are connected to your database, however it's not recommended that use that user, also you should give him a password with the [`grant`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) command.

if you want to see the user that you are using, you can use:

```
mysql> select current_user;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to access your database / tables when you see mysql>  If it doesn't give you an error, then your password most likely is still not set for the root account.  If this is the case, you can go ahead and execute this query to set your root password.

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'your new password';
```